# How to fill/shade the area of two lines that overlap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, overlap

In `ggplot2`, I am trying to fill/shade the area of two lines that overlap. Each line represents a species in a 24-hour period, and the shaded area represents the species overlap. I have tried `geom_ribbon()`, but cannot seem to figure out the ymin and ymax, and `geom_polygon()` seems to only work best when filling between vertical and horizontal lines. For simplification, I am including sample data, but the issue is the exact same as my data.

```
library(overlap)
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
data(kerinci)
head(kerinci)

# Convert time to radians
timeRad <- kerinci$Time * 2 * pi

# Filter species and time
tig2 <- timeRad[kerinci$Zone == 2 & kerinci$Sps == 'tiger']
mac2 <- timeRad[kerinci$Zone == 2 & kerinci$Sps == 'macaque']

# Create density overlap plot with 'Overlap' package plot
overlapPlot(tig2, mac2, main="Zone 2")

# Create df of tig and mac density and time values
tigmac <- overlapPlot(tig2, mac2, main="Zone 2")

# Create density overlap plot in ggplot2
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=tigmac, aes(x=x, y=densityA), color = "black") +
  geom_line(data=tigmac, aes(x=x, y=densityB), color = "blue", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0))+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  #geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=densityA, ymax=densityB), fill = "red", alpha=0.5)+
  xlab('Time') +
  ylab('Density of Activity')
p
```

I have provided photos to illustrate the `overlap` package plot output with the shaded in area and another how what my current `ggplot2` plot looks like. The code will also produce these exact plots.

[Overlap package- density overlap plot with shaded in area between overlapping lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYRYe.png)

[ggplot2 package- no shaded in area between overlapping lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNaqB.png)

My end result is to have my `ggplot2` plot identical to the plot created by the `overlap` package. I want to have the area between the two overlapping lines shaded in.

Answer (score 1):

Just judging by how you want your output data to look like, it seems like `geom_area()` would do the trick. You can take the pairwise minimum with `pmin()`.

Example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(overlap)
#> Warning: package 'overlap' was built under R version 4.0.4

data(kerinci)

timeRad <- kerinci$Time * 2 * pi

tig2 <- timeRad[kerinci$Zone == 2 & kerinci$Sps == 'tiger']
mac2 <- timeRad[kerinci$Zone == 2 & kerinci$Sps == 'macaque']

tigmac <- overlapPlot(tig2, mac2, main="Zone 2")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(tigmac, aes(x)) +
  geom_area(aes(y = pmin(densityA, densityB)),
            alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = densityA, colour = "A")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = densityB, colour = "B"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>